# Django : how to avoid hard code value of table field

Tags: django-models

i have a model `VideoCategory` which is a `ForeignKey` in `Videos` model

```
class VideoCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
```

****above model will have a id field in table which is pk****

one of the web page i want to show the videos from only particular category, say category whose name is "instructional videos" and id is 107.

then what i did:
i constructed a query on the basis of id like :
*I coud have used the name field but it would not solve anything*

```
Videos.objects.filter(category__id=107)[:1]   // 107 is hard coded
```

This will break the code when the **id** in the table is changed or deleted (which is quite the posiblity).

Is there any way around this ?

Comment: How did you determine the id of the category i`instuctional videos` is 107 ? Is there a way to get the object id for instructional videos ?

Comment: right from database table

Comment: What is the usecase ? I mean what in the code makes you request for `Videos.objects.filter(category=107)`?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the keyword "_set" :

```
VideoCategory.objects.get(name="my_category_name").Videos_set.all()
```